# Why is there a small (sub ms) difference between T-SQL current datetime functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

There is a small difference in the current date/time functions compared to the System date/time functions.

```
SELECT 'SYSDATETIME()      ' AS 'Date Time Function', SYSDATETIME() AS 'Result' UNION
SELECT 'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()', SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() UNION
SELECT 'SYSUTCDATETIME()   ', SYSUTCDATETIME() UNION
SELECT 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP UNION
SELECT 'GETDATE()          ', GETDATE() UNION
SELECT 'GETUTCDATE()       ', GETUTCDATE()
```

returns the following results

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   2014-03-12 12:17:59.9170000 +00:00
GETDATE()           2014-03-12 12:17:59.9170000 +00:00
GETUTCDATE()        2014-03-12 16:17:59.9170000 +00:00
SYSDATETIME()       2014-03-12 12:17:59.9192944 +00:00
SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() 2014-03-12 12:17:59.9192944 -04:00
SYSUTCDATETIME()    2014-03-12 16:17:59.9192944 +00:00
```

Why the discrepancy between the three "SYS" prefixed options and the other three?

Comment: Precision looks like one  of the differences - if you run these repeatedly, you only ever get the first 3 to within 3 decimal places

Comment: 1st 3 functions return a DATETIME (precision of 3.3ms) remainder return a more precise DATETIME2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Charleh - it's because of different accuracy. `current_timestamp`, `getdate()` and `getutcdate()` return `datetime` while `sysdatetime()` and `sysutcdatetime()` return `datetime2`. 
Although `sysdatetimeoffset()` returns `datetimeoffset`, datetimeoffset's accuracy is equal to datetime2's accuracy.

If you look up getdate() on msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) you even get the note:

> SYSDATETIME and SYSUTCDATETIME have more fractional seconds precision
>   than GETDATE and GETUTCDATE....

For a complete list of datetypes see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The first 3 functions return a `DATETIME` (precision of 3.3ms) the remainder return a more precise `DATETIME2`.

```
select cast('00:00:00.195' as datetime)
select cast('00:00:00.195' as datetime2)

1900-01-01 00:00:00.197
1900-01-01 00:00:00.1950000
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here.

First, as others mentioned in comments, first 3 functions have different precision than last 3.

Second, if you run this query several times, you'll notice, that for both sets there will be internal differences (ie. `SYSDATETIME()` will return different fraction of a second than `SYSUTCDATETIME()`, because `UNION` takes some time, too :).

I think that this select will return same fractions of a second in both sets of functions more often than yours:

`SELECT 
    SYSDATETIME() AS 'SYSDATETIME()      ',
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() as 'SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()',
    SYSUTCDATETIME() as 'SYSUTCDATETIME()   ',
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  ', 
    GETDATE() as 'GETDATE()          ',
    GETUTCDATE()  as 'GETUTCDATE()       '`